# Modelling multiple many-many relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

After reading [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), some answers here and other docs I am still confused about how to model this relationship.

Thinking of a model where there are objects User and Group, where users can be ordinary members of a group or have management privilege (create group, invite user, remove user, remove group) I want both objects to have two many-many relationships with each other.

- user.memberOfGroups = a list of groups the user belongs to
- group.userMembers = a list of all users who are members of the group
- user.managedGroups = a list of groups the user has management
  privileges for
- group.managingUsers = a list of users with management privilege for
  the group

Is this going to work?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :managedGroups, :class_name => "Group", :foreign_key => "managingUsers"
  has_many :memberOfGroups, :class_name => "Group", :foreign_key => "userMembers"

end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :managingUsers, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "managedGroups"
  has_many :userMembers, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "memberOfGroups"

end
```

I have found in a guide how to use scaffold to generate the model objects which is fine with me, I just want to create a basic web service for POST and GET. If the above is correct it should be as simple as creating the model with scaffold and then editing to include the lines shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues:

- Membership and access control should be modeled by different tables.
- Does management of a group imply membership?
- The foreign key design as described would only allow for each user to manage one group/one group to have one manager. In all many:many relationships you'll need a third join model.

This would be a good starting point:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :users_groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_groups
  has_many :users, :through => :users_groups
end

class UsersGroup < ActiveRecord::Base # will be the users_groups table
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validate_presence_of :name # The name of the permission e.g. "manage"
end
```

Comment: I should also mention that there are lots of off-the-shelf gems for role-based access control, here are a few: https://github.com/be9/acl9  https://github.com/ryanb/cancan